# Current standard compliance level of IronPython & IronRuby

Tags: ironpython, ironruby

Does anyone have some numbers on this? I am just looking for a percentage, a summary will be better.

Standards compliance: How does the implementation stack up to the standard language specification?

For those still unclear: I place emphasis on **current**. The IronPython link provided below has info that was last edited more than 2 years back.

Comment: Standards compliance has really become a useless buzzword when people post questions like this, clearly unaware of what they even mean.

Comment: So Rich B, what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sites usually have updates as to how their 'compliance' is progressing:

IronPython -

http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython
http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Regression%20Tests&referringTitle=More%20Information

IronRuby -

http://www.ironruby.net/

In fact from the IronRuby site -

"We showed IronRuby dispatching some static and dynamic Rails requests at RailsConf this year. We are running the RubySpecs to measure our conformity with Ruby and we're passing the core specs at a 71% rate (12026 / 16793 expectations for RubySpec core)."

Answer (score 1):

IronRuby has a site that  shows the updated numbers: http://www.ironruby.info

Answer (score 0):

We don't actively track these kinds of numbers, but you could download them and run them against the respective test suites for the languages if you wanted to boil it down to a single numeric value.

Comment: And no-one has this number off the top of their head? :|

Answer (score 0):

Found an [update](http://blog.jimmy.schementi.com/2009/07/ironruby-at-oscon-2009-mono-moonlight.html).

They claim 85% now. Not bad  :)